# how to set where clause with variable in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, dynamic

I'm trying to make below where clause  more flexible, i.e. when FLAG column from table 'aa' equals to 'Y', then where clause equals to 'where 1=1'. How can I add into below dynamic SQL?

```
DECLARE @WhereClause NVARCHAR(300) = N' WHERE aa.pt <> ''Ins'' ';


SET @Sql = 
'insert into '+ @DbName  
+ ' ([TimeStamp], RECORD_ID, CREATED) 
'+ 'select 
        GetDate()
        , aa.RECORD_ID
        , aa.CREATED
    from #TempAudit aa 
    LEFT JOIN [' + @tableName + '] bb on aa.RECORD_ID = bb.ROW_ID 
    ' + @WhereClause
```

To clarify it further, what I want to achieve is, when aa.FLAG = Y, then I don't need the condition 'aa.pt <> 'Ins'' anymore. It's something like below but i think the format won't work.

```
DECLARE @WhereClause NVARCHAR(300) = N' WHERE aa.pt <> ''Ins'' ';
 DECLARE @WhereClause2 NVARCHAR(300) = N' WHERE 1=1';
SET @Sql = 
'insert into '+ @DbName  
+ ' ([TimeStamp], RECORD_ID, CREATED) 
'+ 'select 
        GetDate()
        , aa.RECORD_ID
        , aa.CREATED
    from #TempAudit aa 
    LEFT JOIN [' + @tableName + '] bb on aa.RECORD_ID = bb.ROW_ID 
    ' + 'case when aa.FLAG = ''Y'' then @WhereClause2  else @WhereClause'
```

Comment: Like that? `... = N' WHERE aa.pt <> ''Ins'' OR aa.flag = ''Y'''`

Comment: Which rdbms are you using?

Comment: I think your dynamic sql has some extra single quotes in it.  Plus you have insrot into @DBname?  I think that should be a table name?  or is your variable just not named well

Comment: I would recommend printing the results before executing.. that'll help you to find the quote problem... instead of using the quotes change it to CHAR(39). That will help to minimize those problems...

Comment: @digital.aaron sql server

Comment: @Brad  thats another table name. i will rename it

Comment: @kim lage i dont have issue with current code. I just want to modify it to make it more flexible.

Comment: @stickybit No not like that...i edited the question to make it more clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, which you didn't understand as it seems:

If you have an expression, that goes like `A OR B`, that expression will be true if (1) `A` is true and `B` is false, if (2) `A` is false and `B` is true or if (3) `A` is true and `B` is true. It's only false, when (4) both, `A` and `B` are false.

That follows, that you can write your `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE aa.pt <> 'Ins' OR aa.flag = 'Y'
```

Let `A` be `aa.pt <> 'Ins'` and `B` be `aa.flag = 'Y'` here. If `aa.flag = 'Y'` is true case (2) or (3) apply and the condition is true, regardless of `aa.pt <> 'Ins'`. If `aa.flag = 'Y'` is false the condition is true if and only if `aa.pt <> 'Ins'` is true, because of case (1). Otherwise case (4) applies and the condition is false.

That's exactly the logic you want to achieve. It just doesn't use any dynamic SQL acrobatics here (which most likely won't work anyway, as you don't know the values when building the string, hence cannot decide what clause to put there).

Comment: i got your point thank you. I created another variable called '@whereclause2' for this special case, because the original variable is being use  in other places in the SP. `DECLARE @WhereClause2 NVARCHAR(300) = N' WHERE aa.OPERATION <> ''Insert'' OR aa.EMP_FLG = ''Y''' ;
                                `